# Using ifelse to insert a vector as a new column

Tags: r, if-statement

I’d like to use an if statement to create a new column from a vector. However, the result only inputs the first value from the vector all the way down the column. Is there a way to get it to put the vector in? I’ve tried c() and as.character().
Any help much appreciated!

```
data <- data.frame(n = seq(1:21))
ladder1 <- c(50, 75, 100, 125, 150, 200, 250, 300, 350, 400, 450, 475, 500, 550, 600, 650, 700, 750, 800, 850, 900, 950, 1000)
ladder2 <- c(50, 75, 100, 200, 250, 300, 350, 400, 450, 475, 500, 550, 600, 650, 700, 750, 800, 850, 900, 950, 1000)
data$ladder <- ifelse(nrow(data) == 23, ladder1,
                      ifelse(nrow(data) == 21, ladder2))
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`ifelse` outputs vector of same length as the variable you are testing which is of length 1 here (`nrow(data) == 23`) so it output only the 1st variable which is recycled throughout the column.

Use `if`/`else` instead :

```
data$ladder <- if(nrow(data) == 23) ladder1 else if(nrow(data) == 21) ladder2
```

Answer (score 1):

Since you're just switching between two conditions, you could also use `switch`:

```
data$ladder <- switch(as.character(nrow(data)), "23" = ladder1, "21" = ladder2)
```

Or even:

```
data$ladder <- get(c("ladder1", "ladder2")[c(23, 21) %in% nrow(data)])
```